# Why my batch job is running without stop when i call the rest api which has only one employee

Tags: spring-batch

Why batch job is running without stop when call the rest api which has  only one json record.I have tried to fix the issue by checking the other resources and i could not found any solution.I think the problem is custom Item reader.Custom itemreader is going infinite loop.Could please help me where im doing wrong

If i comment below code in read() method it works how do i know when json is finished reading so that i can return null:

```
if(employee != null){
            logger.info("After the  rest read method"+employee);
           return  employee;
          }
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {

    @GetMapping("/employee")
    public Employee getEmployeeByID()  {
        return new Employee(7000,"lombok15","lombok10","8676876866","lombok15","AB6876");
    }

}
```

CustomerItemReader:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeItemReader implements ItemReader<Employee> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("EmployeeItemReader.class");
    private static final String REST_URL = "http://localhost:9590/api/employee";
    private Employee employee = null;


    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public Employee read() {
        Employee employee = null;

        logger.info("inside rest read method"+employee);
        logger.info("Fetching the employee date from the database");

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<Employee> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(REST_URL,Employee.class);
        employee = response.getBody();

          if(employee != null){
            logger.info("After the  rest read method"+employee);
           return  employee;
          }
        return null;
    }


}
```

SpringBatchConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SpringBatchConfig.class");

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                   StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                   ItemReader<Employee> itemReader,
                   ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> itemProcessor,
                   ItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter
    ) {

        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("EMPLOYEE-FILE-WRITTER-JOB")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .build();


        return jobBuilderFactory.get("EMPLYEE-FILE-JOB")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Employee> itemReader(){
        return  new EmployeeItemReader();
    }

}
```

Comment: `My actual question is if i use inbuilt ItemReader scheduling is working but if i use normal class name that extends IteamReader then scheduler is not working`: I can't see why scheduling wouldn't work with a custom reader. Before talking about scheduling, is your job working as expected with your custom reader?

Comment: Hi Yes my job is working but it is not stopping it is continuously running without stop

Comment: That's probably because your item reader never returns null. First, make sure your job is working as expected without the scheduling part, then you can add scheduling. BTW, your scheduling configuration LGTM.

Comment: Mahmoud what you said is right so i changed the question  and code to use commandline runner instead of scheduler.I still could not find where i was doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the way read() method is working.It is working.

```
@Override
    public Employee read() throws Exception {

        logger.info("Reading the information of the next employee");

        if (employeeDataIsNotInitialized()) {
            employeeData = fetchStudentDataFromAPI();
        }

        Employee nextEmployee = null;

        if (nextEmployeeIndex < employeeData.size()) {
            nextEmployee = employeeData.get(nextEmployeeIndex);
            nextEmployeeIndex++;
        }

        logger.info("Found employee: >>>>>>>>>", nextEmployee);

        return nextEmployee;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to see you fixed your issue.